# PVC is mounted as read only file system

Tags: linux, mount, kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes and i have found an issue with the PVCs.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create resources using Helm, deployment, configMap, PVCs
2. On the PVC, `accessMode` is set to `ReadWriteOnce`
3. Mount PVC into at a specific path in the container

`image: php-apache
 ...
 volumeMounts:
  - name: data
    mountPath: /var/www/html/data
volumes:
 - name: data
   persistentVolumeClaim:
   ...`

When i try to copy files to the `data` path, using `kubectl cp`, k8s states that the file system is `readOnly`

What i am not doing right.